# SAML token retrieval through Apache cxf & spring WS

Tags: rest, cxf

I have requirement to retrieve a SAML token from a WS request. How can I achieve this in APACHE CXF ans SPRING WS?

If there are code samples to refer or articles, I will be glad to learn from them.

Another question how can I protect a REST service invocation? In SOAP WS, I will have SAML token that contains user principle. Pointers to these will really help me

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

The best source for information along these lines is probably here:

http://cxf.apache.org/fediz.html